# Difference between prod and cumprod in python

Tags: python, pandas, math, statistics

I cant figure what is the difference between the following methods:

1. `prod()`
2. `cumprod()`

And when do I use them

Comment: `pd.Series([2,2,3]).prod()` gives you `12`, while `pd.Series([2,2,3]).cumprod()` gives `pd.Series([2,4,12])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `prod` method is just do simple multiplication of all the elements.

While the `cumprod` method do multiplication of the elements that comes before the element in the current position.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series([1,2,3,4]).prod()
# output 24
# 1*2*3*4
pd.Series([1,2,3,4]).cumprod()
# output
# 0     1
# 1     2
# 2     6
# 3    24
# for position 0 it just the element -> 1
# for position 1 it 1*2 = 2
# for position 2 it 1*2*3 = 6
# for position 3 it 1*2*3*4 = 24
```

Answer (score 2):

`prod()` simply calculates the multiplication of the values with each other.

`cumprod()` returns a Series of the cumulative product, i.e. the first element will be itself, the second - the multiplication of the two first elements, the third - multiplication of the three first elements and so on..

Example:

```
pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5]).prod()
```

will output 120, while:

```
pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5]).cumprod()
```

will output a Series of [1,2,6,24,120]

Ref - Pandas docs:
[prod()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.Series.prod.html?highlight=prod#pandas.Series.prod)
[cumprod()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25.3/reference/api/pandas.Series.cumprod.html?highlight=series.cumprod#pandas.Series.cumprod)

Answer (score 0):

prod() simply returns the final product of all the values in the series. In the example above it returns an int value but it could be a float if you had used float values in your example.

cumprod() returns the "cumulative product" which in the form of another series. The cumulative product is a sequence of the partial products of a sequence. As an example the cumulative product of (a, b, c) is (a, ab, abc).
Tom